# File transfer error

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making an application, and at some point it does the following: Checks if a file that will be created, already exists in a directory (output), if it exists, he sends for the Errors folder, if not, it sends to the output folder. But comes a point where the program transfers the file to the folder errors, and buga, saying that the file does not exist, for example, he just transfer it t file (49) .png, and he again read the same file ! Funny is only in some cases it

```
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(entrada + "t (" + i + ").png")){


        string[] datas1 = Spire.Barcode.BarcodeScanner.Scan(@"C:\\QTRACK\\Entrada\\PNG\\t (" + i + ").png");

        this.textBox1.Text = datas1[0];

        foreach (string code in datas1)
        {
            DirectoryInfo exit = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:/QTRACK/Erro/");
            FileInfo[] teste = exit.GetFiles("*.png");
            x = teste.Length +1;

            for (c = x; c <= 1000000000; c++)
            {

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(saida + code + ".png"))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(entrada.ToString() + "t (" + i + ").png", erro + "e" + c + ".png");

                }

                else
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(entrada.ToString() + "t(" + i + ").png", saida + code + ".png");
                }

            }
        }

    }
    else
    {

    }                
    }
```

}

It gives the error `FileNotFoundExecption`, however, was himself who changed the file and're trying to change again. Please help.

Comment: `@"C:\\QTRACK` translates as it appears, remove the `@` decorator (oir use it but with unescaped slashes)

Comment: Just curious - did you know about the FileSystemWatcher class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: OK , I make this , but error continues

Comment: No , i don't . I'll read

Comment: You are missing a space in your filename in the else condition. "t("

Comment: Not is "t(" cause one people correct the code in here , but in the visualstudio are with space